# Searching and Sorting on ElasticSearch

Tags: node.js, search, elasticsearch

I am implementing ES as my SE and I have some questions about what am I doing wrong.

The main idea is to have a set of posts that I want to search over some text fields and sort the results by relevance and then by creation date (one of the fields). I'm using node js with the default es library.

Here is my mapping:

```
{
  "version": 1,
  "conf": {
    "settings": {
      "analysis": {
        "filter": {
          "snowball": {
            "type": "snowball",
            "language": "English"
          },
          "english_stemmer": {
            "type": "stemmer",
            "language": "english"
          },
          "english_possessive_stemmer": {
            "type": "stemmer",
            "language": "possessive_english"
          },
          "stopwords": {
            "type": "stop",
            "stopwords": ["_english_"]
          },
          "worddelimiter": {
            "type": "word_delimiter"
          }
        },
        "tokenizer": {
          "nGram": {
            "type": "nGram",
            "min_gram": 3,
            "max_gram": 20
          }
        },
        "analyzer": {
          "custom_analyzer": {
            "type": "custom",
            "tokenizer": "nGram",
            "filter": [
              "stopwords",
              "asciifolding",
              "lowercase",
              "snowball",
              "english_stemmer",
              "english_possessive_stemmer",
              "worddelimiter"
            ]
          },
          "custom_search_analyzer": {
            "type": "custom",
            "tokenizer": "standard",
            "filter": [
              "stopwords",
              "asciifolding",
              "lowercase",
              "snowball",
              "english_stemmer",
              "english_possessive_stemmer",
              "worddelimiter"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "mappings": {
      "posts": {
        "model": "Post",
        "properties": {
          "id": {
            "type": "long"
          },
          "title": {
            "type": "string",
            "analyzer": "custom_analyzer",
            "boost": 5
          },
          "description": {
            "type": "string",
            "analyzer": "custom_analyzer",
            "boost": 4
          },
          "categories": {
            "type": "string",
            "analyzer": "custom_analyzer"
          },
          "seller": {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
              "id": {
                "type": "long"
              },
              "username": {
                "type": "string",
                "analyzer": "custom_analyzer",
                "boost": 1
              },
              "firstName": {
                "type": "string",
                "analyzer": "custom_analyzer",
                "boost": 3
              },
              "lastName": {
                "type": "string",
                "analyzer": "custom_analyzer",
                "boost": 2
              }
            }
          },
          "marketPrice": {
            "type": "float"
          },
          "currentPrice": {
            "type": "float"
          },
          "discount": {
            "type": "float"
          },
          "commentsCount": {
            "type": "integer",
            "index": "not_analyzed"
          },
          "likesCount": {
            "type": "integer",
            "index": "not_analyzed"
          },
          "created": {
            "type": "date",
            "index": "not_analyzed"
          },
          "modified": {
            "type": "date",
            "index": "not_analyzed"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I have indexed 10 documents:

```
  | id | title   | description         | market_price | item_condition | iso | comment_count | created     |
  | 1  | Post 1  | Post 1 Description  | 1            | 1              | 1   | 1             | 2014/01/01  |
  | 2  | Post 2  | Post 2 Description  | 1            | 1              | 1   | 1             | 2014/01/02  |
  | 3  | Post 3  | Post 3 Description  | 1            | 1              | 1   | 1             | 2014/01/03  |
  | 4  | Post 4  | Post 4 Description  | 1            | 1              | 1   | 1             | 2014/01/04  |
  | 5  | Post 5  | Post 5 Description  | 1            | 1              | 1   | 1             | 2014/01/05  |
  | 6  | Post 6  | Post 6 Description  | 1            | 1              | 1   | 1             | 2014/01/06  |
  | 7  | Post 7  | Post 7 Description  | 1            | 1              | 1   | 1             | 2014/01/07  |
  | 8  | Post 8  | Post 8 Description  | 1            | 1              | 1   | 1             | 2014/01/08  |
  | 9  | Post 9  | Post 9 Description  | 1            | 1              | 1   | 1             | 2014/01/09  |
  | 10 | Post 10 | Post 10 Description | 1            | 1              | 1   | 1             | 2014/01/010 |
```

Assume that the seller info is there two, I don't add it here because the post will be extensive.

My query is:

```
GET /clamour_develop/_search
{
     "query": {
         "multi_match": {
         "query":    "post 1",
         "fields":   [ "title", "description", "seller.first_name", "seller.last_name",     "seller.username" ],
         "analyzer": "custom_search_analyzer"
         }
     },
     "sort": [
       {
         "_score":{
           "order": "desc"
         }
       },{
         "created": {
           "order": "desc"
         }
       }
     ]
 }
```

I expect to receive the documents in the order

```
 Post 1
 Post 10
 Post 9
 Post 8
 Post 7
 Post 6
 Post 5
 Post 4
 Post 3
 Post 2
```

But I get

```
 Post 1
 Post 10
 Post 8
 Post 3
 Post 9
 Post 7
 Post 6
 Post 4
 Post 2
 Post 5
```

## EDIT:

https://gist.github.com/bitgandtter/5d3419840fd0508ce356

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Print the score; I'll bet they're different for 2-9.  Then the next question is "why?".

Comment: what score do your documents have for your query?  by default scoring includes things like the document timestamp so this may be affecting your results.

Comment: yes the score its different for each document: 1:"sort": [0.35328037,1388534400000] 
10:"sort":[0.053425744,1389312000000]
8:"sort": [0.053425744,1389139200000]
3:"sort": [0.053425744,1388707200000]
9:"sort": [0.046131223,1389225600000]
7:"sort": [0.046131223,1389052800000]
6:"sort": [0.046131223,1388966400000]
4:"sort": [0.046131223,1388793600000]
2:"sort": [0.046131223,1388620800000]
5:"sort": [0.02080632,1388880000000]

Comment: @OllyCruickshank i really dont know, what should i do? i mean the result score for that query its the previous answer, i dont know if i need to do something else

Comment: Please let ES explain the calculating score with:
GET /clamour_develop/_search?explain
and then type your query... 
Maybe you find out how ES will produce the result.

Comment: hey @s.kwiotek y add a gist url with the explain result, can you help me please. Thanks

Comment: Elasticsearch computes the score using a lexicographic order since your field is a string. You'll need to specify the id of the post in a numeric field and then sort on it!

Comment: @eliasah the order i preview its because im ordering for score an then for created field that its a date field. so as i create post 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 in a consecutive order i want to receive the same order.

Comment: So actually what you are seeking for is a way to sort by score and a giving field, right?

Comment: yes @eliasah i want to sort for score first and then for created date, so i can have an order list of the most relevant posts at top and then ordered by its creation date, how can i do that?

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to add the following to your search query :

```
"track_scores": true
```

When sorting on a field, scores are not computed. By setting track_scores to true, scores will still be computed and tracked.

For more details about the sort parameter in the search apis, you can check the official documentation [here](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-sort.html#_track_scores)

Comment: i add the "track_scores": true and nothing happens, the order its the same.

Comment: As I said in a comment before, in a full-text search, the order is lexicographic. You'll need to specify a numeric field on which you sort on. You'll always obtain the order you described in your question if you don't do that. (sorting strings and sorting numeric are different sorting algorithms!) If you add a gist to some documents example so we can reproduce the scenario, we might be able to help you more.

Comment: hi @eliasah thanks for your quick answers and your help, here its a gist https://gist.github.com/bitgandtter/41cfa3d98cd1a7f61096 with the settings mapping info the bulk insert body and the query im using, with that you can recreate the scenario, thanks a lot

Comment: the bulk insert is not a json! can you deal with that plz?

Comment: i update the gist https://gist.github.com/bitgandtter/41cfa3d98cd1a7f61096 you can execute that on sense and checkout the results

Comment: Thanks for the update! Unfortunatly the bulk part is returning this error :{
   "error": "JsonParseException[Unexpected end-of-input: expected close marker for OBJECT (from [Source: [B@2de9d0f2; line: 1, column: 0])\n at [Source: [B@2de9d0f2; line: 1, column: 3]]",
   "status": 500
}

Answer (score 0):

I find out that the calculating score depends on in which shard each Document exists and how many documents reside in each shard. In your case I saw in the explanation of your gist:

```
shard 0, documents(id):9,4,
shard 1, documents(id):5
shard 2, documents(id):1,6
shard 3, documents(id):2,7
shard 4, documents(id):3,8,10
```

You are searching for "post" term and "1" term. It is obviously that doc with id 1 is matching both terms and results in the highest score.
You see that the document with id 5 is the **only one** in shard 5 and the one with the lowest score. Here comes the most significant relevance calculating from ES:
 **Inverse document frequency**. When you look at the formular of this (http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/scoring-theory.html#idf):
`idf(t) = 1 + log ( numDocs / (docFreq + 1))`
 and take your numDocs(maxDocs) value as well as docFreq value out of gist you become for id 5: 
`1 + log ( 1 / 1+1) = 0.30685282` 
So for documents with id 3, 8, 10 the outcome of this formular is
`1 + log ( 3 / 3+1) = 0.71231794`
 You will see this value in your gist under docs with id 3, 8, 10.
When you compare the relevance of the docs for each separate shard, the docs have the same numDocs and docFreq(except doc with id 1 which matches both search terms and therefore has another relevance)
 [1]:0.35328037 [10,8,3]:0.053425744 [9,4,6,2,7]:0.046131223 [5]:0.02080632.

After that consideration the ordering of the field "created" is reached. Take a look at  Theory Behind Relevance Scoring: http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/scoring-theory.html#scoring-theory

Comment: Thanks @s.kwiotek i understand a little more how it works, the question now its what can i do if i want to the order to be 1,10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2 because creation date should be more important (relevant) that the inverse document frequency

Answer (score 0):

After i read more carefully ES doc i found that i can solve the issue enabling the dfs_query_then_fetch query mode. I know its not a good practice but for shorts amount of data it can be helpful.

Some strategy can be enable this mode for newest projects and when ES database grow change over the default mode and keep working on it.