# elasticsearch nested filter return empty result

Tags: search, filter, elasticsearch, nested

I have this mapping:

```
  "post": {
    "model": "Post",
    "properties": {
      "id": {
        "type": "integer"
      },
      "title": {
        "type": "string",
        "analyzer": "custom_analyzer",
        "boost": 5
      },
      "description": {
        "type": "string",
        "analyzer": "custom_analyzer",
        "boost": 4
      },
      "condition": {
        "type": "integer",
        "index": "not_analyzed"
      },
      "categories": {
        "type": "string",
        "index": "not_analyzed"
      },
      "seller": {
        "type": "nested",
        "properties": {
          "id": {
            "type": "integer",
            "index": "not_analyzed"
          },
          "username": {
            "type": "string",
            "analyzer": "custom_analyzer",
            "boost": 1
          },
          "firstName": {
            "type": "string",
            "analyzer": "custom_analyzer",
            "boost": 3
          },
          "lastName": {
            "type": "string",
            "analyzer": "custom_analyzer",
            "boost": 2
          }
        }
      },
      "marketPrice": {
        "type": "float",
        "index": "not_analyzed"
      },
      "currentPrice": {
        "type": "float",
        "index": "not_analyzed"
      },
      "discount": {
        "type": "float",
        "index": "not_analyzed"
      },
      "commentsCount": {
        "type": "integer",
        "index": "not_analyzed"
      },
      "likesCount": {
        "type": "integer",
        "index": "not_analyzed"
      },
      "featured": {
        "type": "boolean",
        "index": "not_analyzed"
      },
      "bumped": {
        "type": "boolean",
        "index": "not_analyzed"
      },
      "created": {
        "type": "date",
        "index": "not_analyzed"
      },
      "modified": {
        "type": "date",
        "index": "not_analyzed"
      }
    }
  }
```

And this query:

```
GET /develop/_search?search_type=dfs_query_then_fetch
{
  "query": {
    "filtered" : {
        "query": {
          "bool": {
            "must": [
              { "match": { "title": "post" }}
            ]
          }
        },
        "filter": {
          "bool": { 
            "must": [
              {"term": {
                "featured": 0
              }},
              { 
              "nested": {
                "path": "seller",
                "filter": {
                  "bool": {
                    "must": [
                      { "term": { "seller.firstName": "Test 3" } }
                    ]
                  }
                },
                "_cache" : true
              }}
            ]
          } 
        }
    }
  },
  "sort": [
    {
      "_score":{
        "order": "desc"
      }
    },{
      "created": {
        "order": "desc"
      }
    }
  ],
  "track_scores": true
}
```

I wait 25 results because i have 25 post indexed. But i get an empty set. If i remove the nested filter all work just fine. I want to be able to filter for the nested object

## EDIT:

In my settings i have:

```
    "analyzer": {
      "custom_analyzer": {
        "type": "custom",
        "tokenizer": "nGram",
        "filter": [
          "stopwords",
          "asciifolding",
          "lowercase",
          "snowball",
          "english_stemmer",
          "english_possessive_stemmer",
          "worddelimiter"
        ]
      },
      "custom_search_analyzer": {
        "type": "custom",
        "tokenizer": "standard",
        "filter": [
          "stopwords",
          "asciifolding",
          "lowercase",
          "snowball",
          "english_stemmer",
          "english_possessive_stemmer",
          "worddelimiter"
        ]
      }
    }
```

What im missing here.

Thanks

Comment: Can you post your definition of the `custom_analyzer`? The way it's set up could have something to do with your problem.

Comment: hey @SloanAhrens i update the question with my analizers

Comment: I'm still not able to set up an index like yours to test it. It looks like you have some custom filters defined too? Can you post those also? Some sample documents might be helpful too. It's pretty hard to tell you what the problem is without being able to simulate your system.

Comment: My suspicion, though is that, with your current setup, `{ "term": { "seller.firstName": "Test 3" } }` needs to be `{ "term": { "seller.firstName": "test" } }`, or something similar. Or you will need to adjust your analyzers/mapping. But it's hard to say for sure without testing directly.

Comment: @SloanAhrens on this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27493452/searching-and-sorting-on-elasticsearch/27535866#27535866 i post the same data and mapping but for a different reason, its the same

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Short version:** try this (after updating endpoint and index name):

```
curl -XPOST "http://localhost:9200/my_index/_search?search_type=dfs_query_then_fetch" -d'
{
   "query": {
      "filtered": {
         "query": {
            "bool": {
               "must": [
                  {
                     "match": {
                        "title": "post"
                     }
                  }
               ]
            }
         },
         "filter": {
            "bool": {
               "must": [
                  {
                     "nested": {
                        "path": "seller",
                        "filter": {
                           "bool": {
                              "must": [
                                 {
                                    "terms": {
                                       "seller.firstName": [
                                          "test",
                                          "3"
                                       ],
                                       "execution": "and"
                                    }
                                 }
                              ]
                           }
                        }
                     }
                  }
               ]
            }
         }
      }
   }
}'
```

It worked for me, with a simplified version of your setup. I'll post an an edit with a  longer explanation in a little while.

**EDIT: long version:**

The problem with your query is the analyzer combined with the `term` filter in your query. Your analyzer is breaking the text of the `firstName` field into tokens; so `"Test 3"` becomes the tokens `"test"` and `"3"`. When you use `{ "term": { "seller.firstName": "Test 3" } }` what you're saying is, find a document where one of the tokens for `"seller.firstName"` is `"Test 3"`, and there aren't any documents for which that is true (in fact, there can't be given the way your analyzer is set up). You could use `"index": "not_analyzed"` on that field and then your query would work, or you can use a `terms` filter like I showed above. Here's how I got there:

I started with the index definition you linked to in your comment, and simplified it a little to make it more readable and still maintain the essential issue:

```
curl -XDELETE "http://localhost:9200/my_index"

curl -XPUT "http://localhost:9200/my_index" -d'
{
   "settings": {
      "number_of_shards": 1,
      "number_of_replicas": 0,
      "analysis": {
         "filter": {
            "snowball": { "type": "snowball", "language": "English" },
            "english_stemmer": { "type": "stemmer", "language": "english" },
            "english_possessive_stemmer": { "type": "stemmer", "language": "possessive_english" },
            "stopwords": { "type": "stop",  "stopwords": [ "_english_" ] },
            "worddelimiter": { "type": "word_delimiter" }
         },
         "tokenizer": {
            "nGram": { "type": "nGram", "min_gram": 3, "max_gram": 20 }
         },
         "analyzer": {
            "custom_analyzer": {
               "type": "custom",
               "tokenizer": "nGram",
               "filter": [
                  "stopwords",
                  "asciifolding",
                  "lowercase",
                  "snowball",
                  "english_stemmer",
                  "english_possessive_stemmer",
                  "worddelimiter"
               ]
            },
            "custom_search_analyzer": {
               "type": "custom",
               "tokenizer": "standard",
               "filter": [
                  "stopwords",
                  "asciifolding",
                  "lowercase",
                  "snowball",
                  "english_stemmer",
                  "english_possessive_stemmer",
                  "worddelimiter"
               ]
            }
         }
      }
   },
   "mappings": {
      "posts": {
         "properties": {
            "title": {
               "type": "string",
               "analyzer": "custom_analyzer",
               "boost": 5
            },
            "seller": {
               "type": "nested",
               "properties": {
                  "firstName": {
                     "type": "string",
                     "analyzer": "custom_analyzer",
                     "boost": 3
                  }
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}'
```

Then I added a few test docs:

```
curl -XPUT "http://localhost:9200/my_index/posts/1" -d'
{"title": "post", "seller": {"firstName":"Test 1"}}'
curl -XPUT "http://localhost:9200/my_index/posts/2" -d'
{"title": "post", "seller": {"firstName":"Test 2"}}'
curl -XPUT "http://localhost:9200/my_index/posts/3" -d'
{"title": "post", "seller": {"firstName":"Test 3"}}'
```

Then ran a simplified version of your query with the basic structure still intact, but with a `terms` filter instead of a `term` filter:

```
curl -XPOST "http://localhost:9200/my_index/_search?search_type=dfs_query_then_fetch" -d'
{
   "query": {
      "filtered": {
         "query": {
            "bool": {
               "must": [
                  {
                     "match": {
                        "title": "post"
                     }
                  }
               ]
            }
         },
         "filter": {
            "bool": {
               "must": [
                  {
                     "nested": {
                        "path": "seller",
                        "filter": {
                           "bool": {
                              "must": [
                                 {
                                    "terms": {
                                       "seller.firstName": [
                                          "test",
                                          "3"
                                       ],
                                       "execution": "and"
                                    }
                                 }
                              ]
                           }
                        }
                     }
                  }
               ]
            }
         }
      }
   }
}'
...
{
   "took": 5,
   "timed_out": false,
   "_shards": {
      "total": 1,
      "successful": 1,
      "failed": 0
   },
   "hits": {
      "total": 1,
      "max_score": 6.085842,
      "hits": [
         {
            "_index": "my_index",
            "_type": "posts",
            "_id": "3",
            "_score": 6.085842,
            "_source": {
               "title": "post",
               "seller": {
                  "firstName": "Test 3"
               }
            }
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

which seems to return what you're wanting.

Here is the code I used:

http://sense.qbox.io/gist/041dd929106d27ea606f48ce1f86076c52faec91

Comment: Great that works, but ES should not do this for me? how can i specify the analyzer to use in filter? because if i have to do the analysis of the search text my self can be pretty hard

Comment: Read the edit I just made and see if it answers your question. If not I'll see if I can update it. I expect you're going to want to modify your analyzer, and/or use a multi_field.

Comment: Thanks Sloan, after you publish the answer i get the idea that the custom_analyzer its splitting the field, but what i want its to use the custom_search_analyzer on the query so at the moment of use the filters ES split the text for it self so i dont need to split it my self and build the query this way. I have other query with the "multi_match": { 
                  "query": "post",
                  "fields": ["title", "description"],
                  "analyzer": "custom_search_analyzer"
                } in it what i want is to do something similar

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure I understand your question. Have you tried what you're suggesting? Maybe it's worth making another StackOverflow question about it?

Comment: Y es i try but I get an error because I don't find the way to make the filters use a custom analyzer. I will try with another question. Thanks